# Problems with EF6 Model class constructors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

E.g.

```
public class Product
{
    protected Product()
    {
        // This is required for EF
    }

    public Product(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that that can be a [problem](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/test-for-default-constructors-in-models-for-entity-framework/) with EF not getting a default constructor, so we give it a protected parameter-less one to solve that. However, I wanted to see if there are any other problems that I should be aware of?

Comment: What kinds of problems are you worried about?  The only public risk is that one could inherit from the class and call the parameterless base constructor.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is anything in general - the guys who wrote the system I am working on don't seem to use constructors, even in places where it's the absolutely reasonable thing to do. So I was wondering if there is a reason (particular to EF6, which I am new to), but google didn't come up with anything except what's mentioned in the post, so I wanted to double check.

Comment: I don't know of any other problems other than the one I mention (a subclass could choose not to call the public base constructor, so you could end up with a `Product` without a `Name`).